# I got an error when I wanted to use tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, anaconda

I got an error when I wanted to use tensorflow.
I just installed tensorflow and I did

```
$ source activate tensorflow
```

command, terminal became tensorflow version like 
(tensorflow)  ~   master 
But I wrote sample.py like

```
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing as mp

core_num = mp.cpu_count()
config = tf.ConfigProto(
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=core_num,
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=core_num )
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

hello = tf.constant('hello, tensorflow!')
print sess.run(hello)

a = tf.constant(10)
b = tf.constant(32)
print sess.run(a+b)
```

and I run this script like  python rote sample.py 
so this error happen

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>


    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"d\n\x10TensorShapeProto\x12-\n\x03\x64im\x18\x02 \x03(\x0b\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\x1a!\n\x03\x44im\x12\x0c\n\x04size\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

So I searched this error, and I found this solution.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11
I wanna do

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip uninstall tensorflow
brew uninstall protobuf
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

commands, but only     `brew uninstall protobuf` command could not be done.
So,I did 3 commands and I did python rote sample.py  again, but almost same error happen.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/Users/username/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"d\n\x10TensorShapeProto\x12-\n\x03\x64im\x18\x02 \x03(\x0b\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\x1a!\n\x03\x44im\x12\x0c\n\x04size\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tb\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

What should I do to fix this?
Furthermore,why this error happen?What is wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57

Comment: From the commands you showed, it appears that you are trying to run a very old version of TensorFlow (0.5.0). Can you try installing a more recent version (e.g. 1.0.1) and let us know if the problem persists?

Answer (score 0):

i just upgraded protobuf to the latest version and it worked for me

```
pip install protobuf --upgrade
```